# Springboot async and multithreading issues

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am trying to migrate my customers to shopify and I have one shopify shop for each country (FR, DE, IT and so on...).
The choice of the shop where the customer will be migrated is based on a specific id (customer.shopId).

Having a large amount of data to process, I preferred to use an asynchronous method.

So I have one shopifyRestClient for each store and the shopifyRestClientFactory is the component that chooses the correct client depending on the customer.shopId.

I also have a service that populates a table where I map the customer id (internal) to the shopify id.

Using the async annotation I end up having customers belonging to the French store on the German store and vice versa. I also noticed a misalignment on the sync table.

Everything works fine if I run the procedure synchronously.

I have a class retrieving all customers an passing each one to  CustomerExporter->upsertShopify

Thanks in advance for your help

**CustomerExporter**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerExporter {

  private ShopifyRestClient shopifyRestClient;
  private ShopifyGraphQLClient shopifyGraphQLClient;

  private final ShopifyRestClientFactory shopifyRestClientFactory;
  private final ShopifyGraphQLClientFactory shopifyGraphQLClientFactory;
  private final ShopifyImportedCustomerSyncService shopifyImportedCustomerSyncService;
  private final ShopifyCustomerMapper mapper;


@Transactional
@Async("CustomerExportThredExec")
public void upsertShopify(Customer customer) {

    init(customer.getShopId());

    ShopifyCustomer shopifyCustomer = mapper.toShopifyCustomer(customer);

    if (!shopifyCustomerExist(customer)) {
        insertNewShopifyCustomer(shopifyCustomer);
        return;
    }

    updateShopifyCustomer(shopifyCustomer);
}


private void init(Long shopId) {
    shopifyRestClient = shopifyRestClientFactory.getByShopId(shopId);
    shopifyGraphQLClient = shopifyGraphQLClientFactory.getByShopId(shopId);
}
}
```

**ShopifyRestClientFactory**

```
@Component
public class ShopifyRestClientFactory {

@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("shopifyFrRestClient")
private ShopifyRestClient shopifyFrRestClient;

@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("shopifyDeRestClient")
private ShopifyRestClient shopifyDeRestClient;


public ShopifyRestClient getByShopId(Long shopId) {

    ShopifyRestClient client;

    switch (shopId.intValue()) {
        case 2:
            client = shopifyFrRestClient;
            break;
        case 3:
            client = shopifyDeRestClient;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("shopId " + shopId + " is not associated with any Rest client");
    }

    return client;
}
}
```

**AsyncConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {

@Bean(name = "CustomerExportThredExec")
public Executor customerThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(0);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("CustomerExport_Thread_");
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
}
```

Comment: Well your class with the async method is quite clearly not thread safe. Make it thread safe. You have 1 instance of `CustomerExporter` now what do you think happens if 10 threads are calling the `upsertShopify` method. What would the value for the `ShopifyRestClient` be for each thread....

Comment: @M.Deinum I am sure and I agree with you that the problem is what you say. I managed to fix it by setting the clients as ThreadLocal instance variables but I was wondering if there is a more conventional way to do this with springboot

Comment: DOn't use a thread local as that will introduce a lot of other issues when not reset proberly. Just set them locally for the method.